# descargar excel desde servidor C# visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, descarga

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en visual studio 2015(C#,.NET,MVC). Genero un éxcel con la librería EPPLUS. El éxcel se genera correctamente como un xlsx, pero al ejecutar el código de la descarga al cliente, el archivo no se descarga ni da error ni excepción.
La ruta es correcta porque si el método "response.TransmitFile" no encuentra el archivo lanza una excepción. El código:

```
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
                response.Clear();
                response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Informe.xlsx");
                response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("/Content/Informe.xlsx"));
                response.End();
```

¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Que excepción te esta lanzando ?, puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar esta excepción.

Comment: Buenas Francisco, no me da ninguna excepción ni error

Comment: Ya revisaste la consola para ver posibles errores en la llamada?, en herramientas para desarrollador de tu navegador (F12)?